# Why does ActiveRecord after_initialize and after_find callbacks documentation mention the block level variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have defined an `after_initialize` and a `after_find` callback in my `User` model as such:

Please, assume that my `User` has an attribute named `email` too.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize do |user|
    puts "You have initialized an object! Email: #{email}"
  end

  after_find do |user|
    puts "You have found an object! Email: #{email}"
  end
end
```

following the documentation that I've found in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find).

This works as expected. I.e. when I call `User.new` or `User.first` I see the output being printed as expected:

```
2.3.3 :001 > User.new(email: 'foo@gmail.com')
You have initialized an object! Email: foo@gmail.com
=> #<User id: nil, email: "foo@gmail.com", password_digest: nil, 
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, email_confirmation_token: nil, 
terms_of_service: false, country_id: nil> 

2.3.3 :002 > User.first
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" 
ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
You have found an object! Email: mary@gmail.com
You have initialized an object! Email: mary@gmail.com
 => #<User id: 10, email: "mary@gmail.com", password_digest: 
"$...", created_at: "2017-06-10 06:46:05", updated_at: "2017-07-02 
09:52:46", email_confirmation_token: "yStnErkVCFC9mYNHKFNYdA", 
terms_of_service: true, country_id: nil>
```

My question is why does the documentation of the callbacks mention the presence of the block local variable `user`? As you can see from what I have experienced above, the `user` local variable is not used, but I still have access to the `User` instance instantiated and/for found.

Comment: Check [the rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) on Active Record Callbacks and the `ActiveRecord::Callbacks`[documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Comment: Already did, dont undersand

Answer (score 0):

these callbacks without `record item` (in your case a `user` instance) would have much less sense (if any) - apart from test purposes like your case when you're just confirming yourself that record has been found by calling `puts`, normally, in real use case you'll probably need this objects to read/modify before using it in your app.

so, when you defined callbacks, `ActiveRecord` stored them internally. `ActiveRecord` assumes that you will need this instance and when calling your block `do ... end`, it does it with found record (`user`).
In theory (I didn't check actual implementation in `ActiveRecord` codebase) could look like:

```
 record = find_record
 if after_find_callback
   after_find_callback.call(record)
 end
```

Comment: This is not correct. I have amended the question content to show that the `user` block level variable is useless. You can still have access to the instance being initialized and/or found.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required, it's optional. You can do either of the following and get the same results. Assume `User` has a `:name` attribute:

```
after_initialize do |user|
  puts user.name
end

after_initialize do
  puts name
end
```

My guess is the documentation uses the `|user|` variable because it is much clearer, especially to new Ruby/Rails developers, when there is an explicit receiver.

In other words, the first option does not change the context (or "lexical scope") of the execution and the definition of `self`, while the second one does, and that can be confusing at first.

Comment: No. It is not required. I have amended the question content to demonstrate the fact that it is not required.

Comment: why not just answer the question then? you took a lot of liberty editing that question

Comment: Cause I didn't have time to search / investigate what was the reason the documentation had this `user` block level variable. Meanwhile, I see @thanh has posted an answer, which might be a good one. Will come back to it.

Comment: It just reads like a completely different question than what was originally asked, so much so that it seems like they would require different answers @p.matsinopoulos

Answer (score -1):

I think it is just used for document, so that people can know what happen inside the block is targeted to `user`, and yes, it is actually not used.

You can define without `user` variable:

```
after_initialize do
  puts "You have initialized an object! Email: #{email}"
end
```

From the [after_initialize source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/69ab3eb57e8387b0dd9d672b5e8d9185395baa03/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb#L68):

```
def after_initialize(&block)
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:after_initialize, yield: true, &block)
end
```

and [source code of on_load method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cfb1e4dfd8813d3d5c75a15a750b3c53eebdea65/activesupport/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb#L35):

```
# Declares a block that will be executed when a Rails component is fully
# loaded.
def on_load(name, options = {}, &block)
  @loaded[name].each do |base|
    execute_hook(base, options, block)
  end

  @load_hooks[name] << [block, options]
end

def execute_hook(base, options, block)
  if options[:yield]
    block.call(base)
  else
    base.instance_eval(&block)
  end
end
```

So because option `yield: true`, the block will be called in `execute_hook` method:

```
if options[:yield]
  block.call(base)
...
```

So, it does not matter what is your variable of the block.

BTW, you can also use `after_initialize` with method instead of block just like other callbacks (`after_save, after_create`):

```
after_initialize :after_initialize_method
def after_initialize_method
  puts "You have initialized an object! Email: #{email}"
end
```

Comment: This is not the right source code. You're looking at source code for Railtie initializers.

Comment: @m.simonborg have you ever tried to debug `after_initialize` code above to see where it goes? And try `after_initialize` without `user` variable?

Comment: I have looked at the implementation of ActiveRecord callbacks, and the code you referenced is not it. I never pass blocks directly to callback methods but prefer passing symbols.

Comment: I don't care if you uses callback with a block or method! My question is "Have you tried `after_initialize with a block` to see what code actually runs and where it starts" instead of just `looked at the implemenation`? The OP asks about block, not methods reference (symbols).

Comment: Yes, I've used it with a block to see what runs. If you wanted to execute a block in the context of an instance (i.e. changing the value of `self`), but also have the option of an explicit receiver (as in the current example, where `|user|` is optional), you would do so with `base.instance_eval(&block)`, not `block.call(base)`. `block.call(base)` would require the explicit variable in the block. on top of that, ActiveRecord callbacks are definitely not implemented in `Railtie::Configuration`. Plus, the ActiveRecord `after_initialize` takes more args than just a block.

Comment: I think your main answer is correct `I think it is just used for document, so that people can know what happen inside the block is targeted to user, and yes, it is actually not used. You can define without user variable`, but the source code you referenced is not right, and the answer doesn't require diving into source code anyway.

Comment: See this Gist that shows what I'm talking about with block context and optional receiver variable, particularly as it pertains to the code you included in your answer `if options[:yield]; block.call(base)` https://gist.github.com/msimonborg/2677bc095a4ec2178fc19edbdbef753d